# How to pass only part of the Json object to the Controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Lets say I have:

```
public class PersonViewModel {
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Uid { get;set; }
 .......
}
```

(in my case viewmodel have over 30 propertys)

and i have a controller action which takes again suck model:

```
public ActionResult postModel(PersonViewModel model) {
    //do stuff
}
```

on the client side i have only some of the propertys of the PersonViewModel because i had to make a custom Json parser becuase built in parser was too slow. 
I thought that if i do something like :

```
var model = new Object();
model.Name = "monkey";
$.post('/nanana/postModel', JSON.stringify({model : model}))
```

Than i would be able to get Name value on the client side i cant. All the propertys of the model on the Server are empty. Do i really need to set every single property on the client side? or are there any ways to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send partial data. As long as the names match with the name in your view model, Model binding will happen and you will get that posted object in your controller. But make sure you are sending it properly.

You need to specify what type of data you are sending in your asynchronous call. Here i am explicitly specifying the `contentType` property.

```
var model = {};
model.Name = "monkey";

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/nanana/postModel",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            console.log('err');
        }
 });
```

Also, As a side note, i would not hard code the path of url property value, It is a safe idea to use the `Url.Action` html helper method to generate the path to the action method. For example, If you are having your script inside the view itself, you can do this,

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '@Url.Action("postModel","Nanna")',
```

If your script is in a separate js file, you can create a variables to hold the urls to different action methods and set the value of those in your views and use that again in your other javascript files of the same page/view.